# jquery asp.net mvc submit form doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

why this code doesn't work?why i can't get alert message..? where is the problem?

```
  $('.msg_txt).keypress(function (e) {
                    if (e.which == 13) {

                        $("#sendform").submit(function () {
                                                $.post($(this).attr("action"),
                                    $(this).serialize(),
                                    function (data) {
                                        alert("ok, this work");
                                    });
                            e.preventDefault();

                        });

                    }
                });
```

my cshtml file..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "Mycontroller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "sendform" }))
              {
        <textarea id="TextArea1" class="msg_txt" name="poruka" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
                  <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Send"  />         
              }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question doesn't contribute to the site, it has a very local audience that it would benefit, and it doesn't show any research efforts.

Comment: Use JSLint: `Error:
Problem at line 1 character 3: Unclosed string.
$('.msg_txt).keypress(function (e) {

Problem at line 1 character 3: Stopping, unable to continue. (6% scanned).
Implied global: $ 1`

Comment: Just checking the error console would have sufficed...

Comment: in console everything is ok..

Answer (score 1):

The part of your code:

```
$('.msg_txt).keypress(function (e) {
```

should be:

```
$('.msg_txt').keypress(function (e) {
```